# Android test with ActivityScenarioRule hanging forever

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm trying to write a simple UI test for my Android app:

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SimpleTest {

    @get:Rule
    val activityRule = activityScenarioRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    fun justPass() {}
}
```

The problem is that this test hangs forever, and the app gets stuck at this screen:

[image: App screen when the test gets stuck.]

It happens both on an emulator and on a real device. The complete title is `androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$EmptyActivity`.

Strangely, the test completes if I press the square button and then select the same screen from the recent apps.

These are my test dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines_version"
testImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:$mockk_version"
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-android:$mockk_version"
```

If I add `androidx.test:rules:1.3.0` and replace `activityScenarioRule` with `ActivityTestRule`, the test completes automatically as I expected. But ActivityTestRule has been deprecated, so I don't think that's a good option.

So what should I do to make this test pass without getting stuck?

## Update

MainActivity is declared in the manifest with launch mode as single instance:

```xml
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    ... 
</activity>
```

If I remove the `launchMode` attribute, the test no longer hangs. Still, it should be possible to test an activity that has that attribute, so I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: I have no idea how to replace ActivityTestRule, but I spent a lot of time to solve that problem. Please, mention me if you will find solution.

Comment: @AlexRmcf Sure! I just created another project from scratch and ran the same test, and it completed without getting stuck. I believe it must be something specific to my project. I'll try to pull some things out and see what happens..

Comment: @AlexRmcf Check out the question update. The problem isn't really solved, but maybe I'm closer to understand why it happens.

Comment: Any further update on this? I am running into the same issue and singleInstance "fixes" for me too, but obviously not ideal.  I found this thread too which feels like the same issue but the fixes mentioned there didn't work for me https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/676

Comment: @spO_oks Unfortunately, my only way out was to change from `singleInstance` to `singleTask`.